# Show $\lim(s_n) = +\infty$ if and only if $\lim(-s_n) = -\infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Show $\lim(s_n) = +\infty$ if and only if $\lim(-s_n) = -\infty$.

I'm not really sure what to do here. I think I use limit laws to prove the problem, but how do I do that in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the point of the problem:

You need to prove if $\{ s_{n} \}$ is a sequence, then the following is true:

$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} s_{n} = \infty \iff \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} -s_{n} = -\infty$$

and that means you have to prove two statements:

1)  if $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} s_{n} = \infty$, then $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} -s_{n} = -\infty$

and

2) $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} -s_{n} = -\infty$, then $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} s_{n} = \infty$.

Now, as we noted, what it means for $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} s_{n} = \infty$ is $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists N$ such that $n \geq N$ implies $s_{n} > \epsilon$.

And, what it means for $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} - s_{n} = -\infty$ is $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists N$ such that $n \geq N$ implies $-s_{n} < - \epsilon$.

Ok, so to prove 1), let's suppose $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} s_{n} = \infty$.  Then that means $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists N$ such that $n \geq N$ implies $s_{n} > \epsilon$.  But if this is true, then multiplying $s_{n} > \epsilon$ on both sides by $-1$ gives $-s_{n} < - \epsilon$, and this is true for all $n \geq N$.  But that's exactly what it means for $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} -s_{n} = -\infty$.

You can prove 2) in the exact same way, just reversed.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. That makes much more sense to me now.

Answer (score 2):

$\lim s_n=+\infty$ $\iff$

For all $M$ there is $N$ such that if $n>N$ then $s_n>M$. $\iff$

For all $M$ there is $N$ such that if $n>N$  then $-s_n<-M$. $\iff$

For all $M$ there is $N$ such that if $n>N$  then $-s_n<M$. $\iff$

$\lim -s_n=-\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of $\lim_n s_n=+\infty$ is that for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists an $N$ such that $s_n>\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N$. The formulation for $-\infty$ is similar.

So assume $\lim_n s_n=+\infty$ and work out that $\lim_n (-s_n)=-\infty$. Then do it the other way around.

Comment: I think you should write down the formulation for $-\infty$, too.  If the OP is having trouble with this question, leaving details like that definition out probably won't help them with whatever they misunderstand.

Comment: Yes, the formulation for −∞ would help a lot.

Comment: @sfgiantsfan19: Take a moment to think. You have the conditions infront of you to get to $+\infty$. How would you modify them to get to $-\infty$? You needed $s_n$ to be an arbitrarily large *positive* number for $+\infty$ right?

Comment: @AlexR. Hmmm so would the formulation just be flipped for −∞? Is that what you meant when you said to do it the other way around?

Comment: @sfgiantsfan19: Yes

Comment: @AlexR. So is this right: $lim (-s_n) = -∞$ for all $ϵ<0$, there exists $N$ such that $s_n<ϵ$ for all $N≥n$?

Comment: @sfgiantsfan19 Close!! But you need $n \geq N$. Do you know why?

Comment: @user46944 Hmmm is it because $n≥N$ is supposed to help imply $s_n<ϵ$?

Comment: @sfgiantsfan19 Yes, you are right.  The $n \geq N$ part is saying "all terms after the $N$-th term in the sequence".  While the $s_{n} < \epsilon$ part is saying that the $s_{n}$'s are getting bigger and bigger in the negative direction.

Comment: @user46944 I do get that part now. But then I just struggle with approaching the next step. Like I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do next :(

Comment: @sfgiantsfan19 I posted an answer.